# using req.headers.authorization gives Network error unable to reach server We could not introspect your endpoint graphQL Context failed: invalid token

Tags: javascript, express, authentication, graphql, apollo-server

I get the token from the login mutation
and put it in the headers,

[image]

but graphql server gives an error when trying to fetch that token using:

```
const auth = req.headers.authorization;
```

the previous line cause server to show this error **before** running the query (no error messages in termenal)
**"Network error: unable to reach server
We couldn't reach your server.We could not introspect your endpoint. Please enable introspection on your server."**

and **after** running the query (users- to get all users) apollo sandbox give this error message **"Context creation failed: invalid token"**

although consoling the auth returns it successfully!!

the code runs successfully when passing the same token directly:

```
const auth = "bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6Im1ncmV3ZXMwQGNocm9ub2VuZ2luZS5jb20iLCJpZCI6MSwiaWF0IjoxNjI4NDIyNTI4LCJleHAiOjE2Mjg0NTg1Mjh9.lmIsq6-G-pDTBrLeCjyiWtePuEesx_sW_cJ0pLty-E0";
```

here is my index.js code

```
const express = require('express');
const { ApolloServer } = require("apollo-server-express");
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const JWT_SECRET = 'f1BtnWgD3VKY';
const  users  = [
 {
    "id":1,
    "name":"Magdalena",
    "email":"mgrewes0@chronoengine.com",
    "gender":"male",
    "mobile":"734-324-1043",
    "cumulativeGPA":92.1,
    "isGraduate":false,
    "friends":[
       {
          "name":"Magdalena",
          "email":"mgrewes0@chronoengine.com",
          "gender":"male",
          "mobile":"734-324-1043",
          "cumulativeGPA":92.1
       },
       {
          "name":"Harman",
          "email":"hgaspero2@1688.com",
          "gender":"male",
          "mobile":"158-265-8979",
          "cumulativeGPA":87.9
       },
    ],
    "age":28,
    "image" : {"name":"ghklk.png", "height": 50 , "width":30},
 },
 {
    "id":2,
    "name":"Lyndell",
    "email":"lgilbee1@google.com.br",
    "gender":"male",
    "mobile":"165-705-3521",
    "cumulativeGPA":90.6,
    "isGraduate":false,
    "friends":[
       {
          "name":"Magdalena",
          "email":"mgrewes0@chronoengine.com",
          "gender":"male",
          "mobile":"734-324-1043",
          "cumulativeGPA":92.1
       },
    ],
    "age":23,
    "image" : {"name":"ghklk.png", "height": 50, "width":30},
 },
 {
    "id":3,
    "name":"Harman",
    "email":"hgaspero2@1688.com",
    "gender":"male",
    "mobile":"158-265-8979",
    "cumulativeGPA":87.9,
    "isGraduate":false,
    "friends":[
       {
          "name":"Magdalena",
          "email":"mgrewes0@chronoengine.com",
          "gender":"male",
          "mobile":"734-324-1043",
          "cumulativeGPA":92.1
       },
       {
          "name":"Harman",
          "email":"hgaspero2@1688.com",
          "gender":"male",
          "mobile":"158-265-8979",
          "cumulativeGPA":87.9
       },
    ],
    "age":26,
    "image" : {"name":"ghrtlk.png", "height": 51, "width":31},
 },
 {
   "id":4,
   "name":"Inna",
   "email":"igummie3@blinklist.com",
   "gender":"male",
   "mobile":"832-900-3701",
   "cumulativeGPA":86.8,
   "isGraduate":false,
   "friends":[
      {
         "name":"Magdalena",
         "email":"mgrewes0@chronoengine.com",
         "gender":"male",
         "mobile":"734-324-1043",
         "cumulativeGPA":92.1
      },
   ],
   "age":22,
   "image" : {"name":"ghklk.png", "height": 52, "width":32},
 },
];
const { typeDefs } = require('./typeDefs');

const { resolvers} = require('./resolvers');

async function startApolloServer(typeDefs, resolvers) {

    const app = express();

    const server = new ApolloServer({
        typeDefs,
        resolvers,
        context: async ({ req }) => {
            const auth = req.headers.authorization || null;
            //console.log(auth); returns: "bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6Im1ncmV3ZXMwQGNocm9ub2VuZ2luZS5jb20iLCJpZCI6MSwiaWF0IjoxNjI4NDIyNTI4LCJleHAiOjE2Mjg0NTg1Mjh9.lmIsq6-G-pDTBrLeCjyiWtePuEesx_sW_cJ0pLty-E0"
            // const auth = "bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6Im1ncmV3ZXMwQGNocm9ub2VuZ2luZS5jb20iLCJpZCI6MSwiaWF0IjoxNjI4NDIyNTI4LCJleHAiOjE2Mjg0NTg1Mjh9.lmIsq6-G-pDTBrLeCjyiWtePuEesx_sW_cJ0pLty-E0";
            const decodedToken = jwt.verify(
                auth.substring(7), JWT_SECRET
            )
            const user = await users.find(u => u.id == decodedToken.id);
            return { user }
        },
    });
    await server.start();
    server.applyMiddleware({ app });
    await new Promise(resolve => app.listen({ port: 7778 }, resolve));
    console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:7778${server.graphqlPath}`);
    return { server, app };
}
startApolloServer(typeDefs, resolvers);
```

resolver code

```
const { UserInputError } = require('apollo-server-express');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const JWT_SECRET = 'f1BtnWgD3VKY';
const resolvers = {
    Gender: {
        MALE: 'male',
        FEMALE: 'female',
    },

    Mutation: {
        login: async (_, args) => {
            const user = await users.find(u => u.email == args.email)
            if ( !user || args.mobile !== user.mobile ) {
              throw new UserInputError("wrong credentials")
            }
            const userForToken = {
              email: user.email,
              id: user.id,
            }
            return { tokenValue: jwt.sign(userForToken, JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '10h' })}
        },
    },

    Query: {
        users: (_, __, context) => {
            if (!context.user) return null;
            return users;
        },
        getUserByID: (_, {id}, context) => {
            if (!context.user) return null;
            return users.find(user => user.id == id)
        },
    },
};
module.exports = { resolvers };
```

typeDefs code

```
const { gql } = require('apollo-server-express');

const typeDefs = gql`
    type User {
      id: ID!
      name: String!
      email: String!
      gender: Gender!
      mobile: String!
      cumulativeGPA:Float!
      isGraduate: Boolean!
      friends: [Friend]
      age: Int!
      image: Image
    }

    enum Gender {
        MALE
        FEMALE
    }

    type Friend{
        name: String!
        email: String!
        gender: Gender!
        mobile: String!
        cumulativeGPA:Float!
    }

    type Image{
        name: String!
        height: Int!
        width: Int!
    }

    type Mutation {
        # setName(userID: ID!, newName: String!): User
        # deleteUser(id: ID!): [User]
        login(email: String!, mobile: String!): Token
    }

    type Token {
        tokenValue: String!
    }
    
    type Query {
        users: [User]
        getUserByID(id: ID!): User
    }
`;

module.exports = { typeDefs };
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@graphql-tools/schema": "^7.1.5",
    "apollo-server": "^3.1.2",
    "apollo-server-express": "^3.0.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "graphql": "^15.5.1",
    "graphql-subscriptions": "^1.2.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
    "subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.9.19"
  }
}
```

i want to use the commented line `const auth = req.headers.authorization;`
insted passing the token directly

operating system is windows 10
browser is chrom

Answer (score 1):

In your apollo sandbox, instead of

```
"bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6Im1ncmV3ZXMwQGNocm9ub2VuZ2luZS5jb20iLCJpZCI6MSwiaWF0IjoxNjI4NDIyNTI4LCJleHAiOjE2Mjg0NTg1Mjh9.lmIsq6-G-pDTBrLeCjyiWtePuEesx_sW_cJ0pLty-E0"
```

try capitalizing the "bearer"

```
"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6Im1ncmV3ZXMwQGNocm9ub2VuZ2luZS5jb20iLCJpZCI6MSwiaWF0IjoxNjI4NDIyNTI4LCJleHAiOjE2Mjg0NTg1Mjh9.lmIsq6-G-pDTBrLeCjyiWtePuEesx_sW_cJ0pLty-E0"
```

Comment: I still need the solution :(

Comment: @entesar I had the same problem and can solved modifyin my index.js file about req. I noticed you're using "apollo-server-express": "^3.0.2", I'm  on "apollo-server-express": "^3.1.2",

Comment: it's not because of the version, its because i add the token inside the double quotation, in apollo headers like appear in image above, when i remove the quotation it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary fix that can be used in the development.

```
if (req.headers.host === 'localhost:<Port number>') {
    return {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove just Quotation
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6Im1ncmV3ZXMwQGNocm9ub2VuZ2luZS5jb20iLCJpZCI6MSwiaWF0IjoxNjI4NDIyNTI4LCJleHAiOjE2Mjg0NTg1Mjh9.lmIsq6-G-pDTBrLeCjyiWtePuEesx_sW_cJ0pLty-E0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Given the code provided by OP, there is only one set of quotes, used for a strong in JavaScript, so this would not work if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apollo sandbox there is a likehood the first character of is missing always confirm whether the copied token matches the original token.
I got the same error("we could not introspect your endpoint"). Until I compared copied token and original one and noticed the original had a missing character

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).